# Dynamically binding "Keypress" in javascript

Tags: javascript, dynamic, bind, keypress, keycode

```
success: function(data) {
            $.each(data.top[field].terms, function(index, result) {
                $('<li>' + result.term + ' [' + result.count + ']</li>')
                    .appendTo($('.input-list-wrapper', $tooltip))
                    .data('field', field)
                    .data('value', result.term)
                    .focus()
                    .bind('keypress', function(e) {
                        console.log('test');
                        if (e.keyCode === 13) {
                            $term.trigger('updateTerm', $(this).data('value'));
                        }
                    })                                              
            });
}
```

I am not able to bind the keypress event dynamically. If i replace the .bind call with .mouseenter or .mouseover it works as intended. I've tried .on .keypress .keyDown .live (.live gave me a undefined function error).

Comment: Be sure the `keypress` behavior is defined for your browser. According to jQuery docs: http://api.jquery.com/keypress/#entry-longdesc . Also, you are binding keypress event to `li` elements? Keep in mind they have to have focus to trigger the keypress event.

Comment: I'ved made sure to trigger the focus but it didn't seems to help. Not sure how to get this working dynamically with keypress.

Comment: First of all, if you use the old method of document.onkeypress does that work?
I'm wondering if this is a JQuery problem or an actual genuine Javascript error

Comment: @user3662516 have you tried jQuery `.keyup(function(e) { ... })`?